# multiple lines in gvim command-line window

Tags: vim

How can I configure gvim's EX command-line window for multiple screen lines?

Note: this window is not the window that pops up when pressing q:
It's the window right below the status line.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I just want multiple lines in the command buffer. It helps because sometimes when resizing the window, gvim gets buggy and cuts off a bit of the command-line.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. if it supports multlines, not simply wrapping, how do you break your line? by pressing `Enter`? the command is gonna fired. btw, I tried a bit, cannot reproduce your problem...

Comment: (I'm using vim 7.0 at work.) the problem isn't reproducing itself when I try again. But I had this setting yesterday in my .vimrc file but blew it away thinking that my .gvimrc was the same. I could swear its possible, but I did a deep internet crawl. Also it's just a 'display' configuration. it doesn't actually change how the command-line operates (i.e. pressing enter just brings back to inputting commands in the first line). the only difference is that when running command that produce multiline messages greater than 2, the window expands one line less.

Comment: it **is** possible. If I can drag the statusline up/down, thus expanding the command-line, then there's a way to make that permanent through a setting.

Comment: yes you can make the window bigger, but it doesn't mean multiple lines. it has auto-wrap. but no `line-break`s. glad to know how can it be set if possible. also what is the use case..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the size of the command-line window with `cmdheight`:

```
set cmdheight=2
```

This will make the command-line window take up two screen lines.  Stick it in your `.vimrc`.  It works the same in `vim` or `gvim` or MacVim or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could try `q:` or `q/` or `q?` or `<c-f>`. Try `:h q`.